# How do expose an application using helm service.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, traefik

I have created a Helm Chart which deploys my app, and it does that well, to expose the app to the outside world (my homelan) I'm using Traefik

If I run the helm install command and type

```
kubectl get svc
```

I get the expected output

```
n8n-deployment LoadBalancer 10.106.99.168 192.168.222.222 5678:30899/TCP 4s
```

If I use

```
kubectl describe svc
```

I can see the following for the service

```
Name: n8n-deployment

Namespace: default

Labels: app.kubernetes.io/instance=n8n-deployment

app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm

app.kubernetes.io/name=n8n-deployment

app.kubernetes.io/version=1.16.0

helm.sh/chart=n8n-0.1.0

Annotations: meta.helm.sh/release-name: n8n-deployment

meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default

Selector: app.kubernetes.io/instance=n8n-deployment,app.kubernetes.io/name=n8n-deployment

Type: LoadBalancer

IP Family Policy: SingleStack

IP Families: IPv4

IP: 10.106.99.168

IPs: 10.106.99.168

LoadBalancer Ingress: 192.168.222.222

Port: n8nport 5678/TCP

TargetPort: 5678/TCP

NodePort: n8nport 30899/TCP

Endpoints: <none>

Session Affinity: None

External Traffic Policy: Cluster

Events:

Type Reason Age From Message

---- ------ ---- ---- -------

Normal IPAllocated 12s metallb-controller Assigned IP "192.168.222.222"
```

However, nothing works

if i run

```
kubectl delete svc n8n-deployment
```

and run

```
kubectl expose deploy n8n-deployment --port 5678 --type LoadBalancer
```

Everything works as expected and I can see the app.

The second I run this command the Traefik dashboard adds another router..

If i run

```
kubectl describe svc
```

again, the only difference which stands out is the line now picks up the endpoint

```
Endpoints: 172.16.184.171:5678
```

Is now populated

My templates/services.yaml looks like this

```
n8n/templates/service.yaml

apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata:

name: {{ include "n8n.fullname" . }}

labels:

{{- include "n8n.labels" . | nindent 4 }}

spec:

type: {{ .Values.service.type }}

ports:

- port: {{ .Values.service.port }}

targetPort: 5678

protocol: TCP

name: n8nport

selector:

app: n8n-deployment
```

What am I missing that stops helm work but the kubectl expose command will?

I've not uploaded everything, but will happily work to understand, I'm a noob and never run helm before. I'm also aware I should be using more variables in things, I'm working on it.

Comment: what is values.yaml values you are passing ?

Comment: The service selector in your template (`app=n8n-deployment`) does not match that of the service described in the first place (`app.kubernetes.io/instance=n8n-deployment,app.kubernetes.io/name=n8n-deployment`)

Comment: Changed my service.yaml to 

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "n8n.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "n8n.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
    app: n8n-deployment
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: n8n-deployment
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: 5678
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: n8n-deployment`
    
And this works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Changed my service.yaml to

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata:


  name: {{ include "n8n.fullname" . }}

  labels:

    {{- include "n8n.labels" . | nindent 4 }}

    app: n8n-deployment

    app.kubernetes.io/instance: n8n-deployment

spec:

  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}

  ports:

    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}

      targetPort: 5678

      protocol: TCP

  selector:

    run: n8n-deployment
```

And this works perfectly, it was missing the line

`app.kubernetes.io/instance: n8n-deployment`